# XSLT not giving output

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Cannot view output of XSLT in Internet Explorer.

cdcatalog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
        <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS</company>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Maggie May</title>
        <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Pickwick</company>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Romanza</title>
        <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.80</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
        <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Black angel</title>
        <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Mega</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <artist>Many</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Grammy</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1999</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>For the good times</title>
        <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Mucik Master</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Big Willie style</title>
        <artist>Will Smith</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
        <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1971</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Soulsville</title>
        <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
        <country>Norway</country>
        <company>WEA</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The very best of</title>
        <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Island</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Stop</title>
        <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>A and M</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
        <artist>T`Pau</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Siren</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Private Dancer</title>
        <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Capitol</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Midt om natten</title>
        <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Medley</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
        <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>DECCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1991</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The dock of the bay</title>
        <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Picture book</title>
        <artist>Simply Red</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Elektra</company>
        <price>7.20</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Red</title>
        <artist>The Communards</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>London</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>EMI</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

cdcatalog.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>.</td>
                        <td>.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I save both file in one folder and I run as right click on cdcatalog.xsl and click on open on internet explorer . But I am not able to get the output. Please help.
I tried for the namespace suggestion but still not getting output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to link the XSL style sheet to your XML document?

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
.
.
</catalog>
```

Assuming the browser you are using is XSLT compliant, when you open the XML file with the above change you should see the HTML output.

Comment: thanks for reply ... I tried to run the xml file but my browser is not giving the output as required ...Explorer ( 9) I am using and I guess it should support the xml ....Please suggest if I need to do some setting to make the browser compactible

Comment: What output do you currently get?  Please check that your XML is well-formed (i.e. every open tag is closed properly).

Comment: I am getting output like same as xml file .....<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<artist>Joe Cocker</artist> <country>USA</country>................... <company>EMI</company> <price>8.20</price> <year>1987</year> </cd> </catalog>

Comment: I tried to add <?xml-stylesheet href="cdcatalog.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?> after <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> but again it is not coming with xsl output  and I am getting output like Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan USA Columbia 10.90 1985 Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler UK CBS Records 9.90 1988 Greatest Hits Dolly Parton USA RCA 9.90 1982 Still got the blues Gary Moore UK Virgin records 10.20 1990 Eros Eros Ramazzotti EU BMG 9.90 1997 One night only Bee Gees UK Polydor 10.90 1998 Sylvias Mother Dr.Hook UK CBS 8.10 1973 Maggie

Comment: @pri You obviously do not know yet how Stackoverflow works. Please [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and find out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Code should never be mentioned in comments, and the info you've given so far does not allow us to identify the problem.

Comment: sorry for that....but I was really trying hard to XSLT worked for my browser....I have tried many thing till now but not getting the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

> I save both file in one folder and I run as right click on cdcatalog.xsl and click on open on internet explorer .

When transforming directly in the browser, it is *not* the XSLT stylesheet file you should open. Open the XML document instead. As Tim has already mentioned, this requires a *reference* in your XML document that links to the stylesheet.

Otherwise, your transformation produces the following output, which is not very meaningful in my opinion:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>.</td>
            <td>.</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Did you perhaps mean to write something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output will be

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Greatest Hits</td>
            <td>Dolly Parton</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Still got the blues</td>
            <td>Gary Moore</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Eros</td>
            <td>Eros Ramazzotti</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>One night only</td>
            <td>Bee Gees</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Sylvias Mother</td>
            <td>Dr.Hook</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Maggie May</td>
            <td>Rod Stewart</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Romanza</td>
            <td>Andrea Bocelli</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>When a man loves a woman</td>
            <td>Percy Sledge</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Black angel</td>
            <td>Savage Rose</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1999 Grammy Nominees</td>
            <td>Many</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>For the good times</td>
            <td>Kenny Rogers</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Big Willie style</td>
            <td>Will Smith</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Tupelo Honey</td>
            <td>Van Morrison</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Soulsville</td>
            <td>Jorn Hoel</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>The very best of</td>
            <td>Cat Stevens</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Stop</td>
            <td>Sam Brown</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bridge of Spies</td>
            <td>T`Pau</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Private Dancer</td>
            <td>Tina Turner</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Midt om natten</td>
            <td>Kim Larsen</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Pavarotti Gala Concert</td>
            <td>Luciano Pavarotti</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>The dock of the bay</td>
            <td>Otis Redding</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Picture book</td>
            <td>Simply Red</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>The Communards</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Unchain my heart</td>
            <td>Joe Cocker</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is taking his code directly from a W3Schools online example, q.v. [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) if you would like to see.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim, I know ;). We get a _lot_ of questions that use code or XML from w3schools, unfortunately.

Comment: @pri Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If your problem is solved, you should accept one of the answers (not necessarily mine).